# How to extract numbers from a string and dumping them as a comma separated values?

Tags: bash

I have a test_file in bash which outputs following on screen . I have no control on the upstream code to print them in a certain way. So, I need to do parse some values from the screen output. 
Here is what I'm doing:

```
MyOut=$(./my_test_file.sh)    # this is my example script which echo's the 
                                 #output
echo $MyOut
```

shows me the following

```
output for different segments IP address: 192.168.0.12 Segment :0xfff Segment Data: 123 23 42 23 4 444 1121 8676 34 530 323 564 523 7878 7328 96
```

my expected results would be a string variable

```
123,23,42,23,4,444,1121,8676,34,530,323,564,523,7878,7328,96
```

comma-separated 16 values getting stored in some variable which I can dump in a text file for further processing.

I tried playing with regular expressions and would like to only extract last 16 numbers in the following output

I did this

```
numbers=$(echo $MyOut | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
```

gives me

```
192 168 0 12 0 123 23 42 23 4 444 1121 8676 34 530 323 564 523 7878 7328 96
```

I need to extract the last 16 numbers. Since it is not a array format , Can I add something in regular expression which only spits out only last 16 numbers delimited by commma ???

btw If you need to look into my_test_file.sh , its just echoing the statements

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "output for different segments "
echo "IP address: 192.168.0.12 Segment :0xfff"                        
echo "Segment Data:"                                                                 
echo "123"                                                                            
echo "23"                                                                          
echo "42"                                                                           
echo "23"                                                                           
echo "4"                                                                           
echo "444"                                                                           
echo "1121"                                                                           
echo "8676"                                                                           
echo "34"                                                                           
echo "530"                                                                           
echo "323"                                                                           
echo "564"                                                                           
echo "523"                                                                            
echo "7878"                                                                            
echo "7328"                                                                            
echo "96"
```

Thanks
Ash

Answer (score 1):

```
MyOut=$(./my_test_file.sh | tail -n +4 | paste -sd ",")
```

The `tail -n +4` will skip to the 4th line of your output and the `paste` will join the lines with a comma instead of a space.

In comments you mention you don't have access to `paste` - what about `tr`?

```
MyOut=$(./my_test_file.sh | tail -n +4 | tr '\n' ',')
```

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks for your reply.  I cannot use 'paste' in the shell as it is blocked and dont have access to make paste work . But yes , it runs very well as expected in my regular bash environment

Comment: @AshSDR, updated my answer (`tr` instead of `paste`)

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample awk script:

```
 text="output for different segments IP address: 192.168.0.12 Segment :0xfff Segment Data: 123 23 42 23 4 444 1121 8676 34 530 323 564 523 7878 7328 96"
 echo $text |awk '{sub(/^.*Segment Data: /,"");gsub(/ /,",")}1'
```

output:

```
123,23,42,23,4,444,1121,8676,34,530,323,564,523,7878,7328,96
```

explantion:

`sub(/^.*Segment Data: /,"")` remove text from line begining to `Segment Data:`

`gsub(/ /,",")` replace all  with `,`

`1` print modified line

Comment: 1 I think you forgot to remove either echo or input.txt from your answer. ,2  also this will not work with the script provided by OP. you can validate by using the original script.

Comment: fixed comment from @PS

Answer (score 0):

Other way:

```
echo "output for different segments IP address: 192.168.0.12 Segment :0xfff Segment Data: 123 23 42 23 4 444 1121 8676 34 530 323 564 523 7878 7328 96" | awk -F'Segment Data: ' '{print $2}' | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

gives you:

```
123,23,42,23,4,444,1121,8676,34,530,323,564,523,7878,7328,96
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only `awk`:

```
./my_test_file.sh |awk -vlast=16 -v RS=    '{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/," ") ; for(i=NF-last+1;i<=NF;i++) if(i!=NF)printf $i",";else print $i}'
123,23,42,23,4,444,1121,8676,34,530,323,564,523,7878,7328,96
```

first used `gsub()` function to remove all the non-digit chars from each line, later looped for last 16 columns. `printf` and `print` both are used to deal with last comma char.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

myout=$(./my_test_file.sh)
read -r -d '' -a parts <<<"$myout"
numlist=${parts[*]: -16}
result=${numlist// /,}

printf '%s\n' "$result"
```

- Using the `my_test_file.sh` given in the question it prints `123,23,42,23,4,444,1121,8676,34,530,323,564,523,7878,7328,96`.
- The code assumes that [IFS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-IFS) has its default value.
- The `read` puts the whitespace-separated parts of the value of `myout` into the array `parts`.  The `-d ''` causes `read` to continue through newlines (otherwise it would stop after reading the first line)  The `-r` option disables weird handling of backslashes in the input (which shouldn't matter here, but it's safest to *always* use `-r` with `read`, and [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will warn if it is missing).
- `numlist=${parts[*]: -16}` sets the `numlist` string to the last 16 elements of the `parts` array, separated by the first character of `$IFS` (by default, a space character).
- `result=${numlist// /,}` sets `result` to the value of `numlist` with all space characters replaced by commas.